# Problem in updating pip on python (visual studio code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip

I'm trying to learn python but have some problems with pip update and installations:
it keeps saying to me that there is an enviroment issue and check permissions
that's what it tells:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/aa/3f4c7bcee2057a76562a5b33ecbd199be08cdb4443a02e26bd2c3cf6fc39/pip-23.3.2-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Accesso negato: 'c:\\program files\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-19.2.3.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 23.3.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

My python version is 3.8.2

python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command

I tried this command, checked the versions and much more but i don't know what to do

Comment: You don't have permissions to that path on the filesystem. Modifications to `C:\Program Files` require administrative permissions. Run the command in an elevated prompt, or reinstall Python to a directory owned by your user profile.

Comment: Please update Python 3.12.1

Comment: Can i ask you what you mean with run the command in an elevated prompt? I'm getting crazy with this shit of pip.

Answer (score 2):

You are lacking the required permissions to make that change. You can run your command prompt as an administrator to gain these permissions, or reinstall Python to a directory where you have the necessary permissions.

Windows restricts your ability to edit certain file paths for the safety of you interacting with your computer. You should be careful when using elevated permissions if you don't know what you're doing, but this one command would be harmless.

My recommendation, though, would be reinstalling Python to a location that does not require these permissions.

Comment: I put my account as administrator, restarted the computer, tried the commands again, but the terminal says the same thing (about permissions). I hate this and wanna trow my pc out my window in this moment, please help me ahhah. Only to know, how much pip are important to a beginner developer?  I don't want to get crazy to update pips if they're not useful for now. Anyway, thank you all for helping

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Python to a folder that you have access?

Comment: if i reinstall it, my projects on visual studio code will not be lost, right? and another question: how i can understand what folder need access and whose not?

Comment: You projects will all remain in tact; those are files that are interpreted by Python, but do not need Python to exist. You could have written them without ever installing Python. You can check permissions of folders in the terminal, but you can also just install to a folder that you interact with frequently, since you clearly have permissions to that folder.

Comment: thank you so much, so kind. I have to bother you with one last question: now i have selected python 3.11 as the editor and its working pip too; what's the difference with the 3.8 version? I'm trying to figure it out searching on internet but found nothing

Comment: For you, they are identical. Of course there are changes but they're not relevant to the average person. There are significant changes between python 2.x and 3.x that you would notice, but dont worry about 3.8 to 3.11